# How do we determine the relation, domain and range when the entries in the ordered pair are more than or equal to $3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A *binary relation* is a relation between two objects. If $x$ is related to $y$ under the relation $\mathbb{R}$, then we write *$_x\mathit{R}_y$*

Thus, $\mathbb{R}=\{(x,y): x\in \text{A, } y \in \text{B } \text{ and }  _x\mathit{R}_y\}$ where $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ are two sets and a relation $\mathbb{R}$ from $\text{A}$ to $\text{B}$ is the *subset* of the *cartesian product* $\text{A} \times \text{B}$.

$\square $ *Domain of the relation* - The set  of first entries of the ordered pairs in a relation.

$\square $ *Range of the relation* - The set  of second entries of the ordered pairs in a relation.

$\bigcirc$ **Question :**

1. Suppose we have three sets $\text{A}$, $\text{B}$ and $\text{C}$, then how do we define a relation between them and what would be the domain and range of that relation?
2. What would be the domain and range of the relation, where we have the cartesian product of more than three sets?

I don't have a strong logic but I think -

- it is obvious that no matter how many sets are there, from the ordered pair of their cartesian product the set of first entries will always be the domain of a relation between those sets (if such a relation exists). But I have no ideas, what to call the second and third entries in each ordered pair.
- my first question is related to composite mapping. If we say *domain* and *range* - the relation should be always binary [such as $\text{A}\to \text{B}$, then $(\text{A}\circ \text{B})\to \text{C}$ ]

  Any explanation is valuable and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a subset of A×B×C.
   It is a collection of triplets.
   Domain, codomain and range are meaningless.
   Instead one uses the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd projections.
2. As a subset of the product of the n sets.
   It is a collection of n-tuplets.
   Again, domain, codomain and range are meaningless.
   Instead one uses the projections, the first through the n-th.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Just to be clear if I have an ordered pair $(1,2,3)$ then is it correct to say that the 1st projection is at $1$, second projection is at $2$ and the third projection is at $3$?

Comment: (1,2,3) is not an ordered pair.

Comment: It was my mistake and thank you for the correction. To be clear if I have an ordered triplet (1,2,3) then is it correct to say that the 1st projection is at 1, second projection is at 2 and the third projection is at 3?

Comment: Yes, @TopoSet32

Comment: In case $(a, b ,c) = ((a,b),c)$ can't we say that the ordered pairs  from  $A\times B$  that are related to some element of $C$ constitute the domain, and that the elements of $C$ to which some ordered pair is related constitute the range?

Comment: No we will not because I do not allow others to speak for me. @RayLittleRock .

Answer (score 0):

I have read that the triplet $(a, b , c)$ can be defined as  $((a,b) , c)$ , that is the ordered pair that has the ordered pair $(a,b)$ as first element and $c$ as second element.

[Definition of the ordered triple (a, b, c) according to Kuratowski's Set Theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500787/definition-of-the-ordered-triple-a-b-c-according-to-kuratowskis-set-theory)

If this is correct, a ternary relation involving elements belonging to  $A$, $B$ and $C$ is a relation from the cartesian product $A\times B$ ( the set of all ordered pairs with a first element coming from $A$ and a second element coming from $B$)  to the set $C$ .

So it is a subset of $( A\times B) \times C$